# Bootstrap select and textbox side by side

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display `dropdown` and `input` side by side as shown in below image.

[image]

I've tried inline forms and input group but all the examples i've seen are showing about alignment of `static text` with span and `input` control side by side

So far, below is what I've tried

```
<div class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" id="phonetype">
                <option value="">Select Phone Type</option>
                <option value="Passport">Mobile Phone</option>
                <option value="SSN">Work Phone</option>
              </select>
    <input class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="">
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/zecatiyuta/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="">
  <div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <select class="form-control" id="phonetype">
                  <option value="">Select Phone Type</option>
                  <option value="Passport">Mobile Phone</option>
                  <option value="SSN">Work Phone</option>
                </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <input class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="">
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer however it is nowhere match to the image I posted.

Comment: I've tried to adjust but it was not working. See the image in question

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group navbar navbar">
        <select class="form-control nav navbar-nav navbar-static-top" id="phonetype">
          <option value="">Select Phone Type</option>
          <option value="Passport">Mobile Phone</option>
          <option value="SSN">Work Phone</option>
        </select>
        <input class="form-control nav navbar-nav navbar-static-top" id="phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It produces this:

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YUDH.png)